# Proper way to use setInterval on multiple HTTP requests with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say you have a list which contains 3 ~ 5 urls. Requests should be made every 5 seconds, one by one. I wrote code like :

```
    setInterval(() => {
    array.foreach(element => {
    request
  .get(element.url)
  .on('response', function(response) {
         console.log(response);
       }
    });
}, 5000)
```

But because the enqueueing setInterval is faster than executing the request, the `.on` callback is not responding. I think, before enqueueing setInterval, I must ensure that the I've finished `.on` callback.

How can I do that?

Comment: You have put your foreach inside setInterval. So within every 5 seconds (5000ms) it will try to execute all get requests. So that means 3 ~ 5 get requests will happen each time. Do you really need that? Or do you need one request to execute and then after 5 seconds, request number 2, and so on?

Comment: I have to execute all get requests each time. The easiest solution is to give setInterval longer than 5 seconds, but I can't calculate the exact time to finish the request.

Comment: You either need to use a success callback, or if you are using RXJS, then you can create observables. Do you know these concepts?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani No, I don't know about those

Comment: Ok, I am going to post an answer in a while. You may need to remove your setInterval or maybe change where you call it. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani Great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend you the [Async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/) module.

If you want a async loop to solve, you can:

```
var i = 0;
async.whilst(
  function() { return i < array.length; },
  function(next) {
    var elemet = array[i++];

    request
      .get(element.url)
      .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        // Do next while 5s passed
        setTimeout(next, 5000);
      }
    }
  },
  function (err, n) {
    // All Task over
  }
);
```

Or if you want try some concurrency:

```
// create a queue object with concurrency 2
var q = async.queue(function(task, next) {
  console.log('request ' + task.url);

  request
    .get(task.url)
    .on('response', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        next();
     }
  }
}, 2);

// assign a callback
q.drain = function() {
    console.log('all task have been processed');
};

// Push a request task to the queue every 5s
setInterval(function () {
  let task = array.shift()
  if (task) {
    q.push(task, function(err) {
        console.log('finished processing', task.url);
    });
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This is the best solution of all answers here. Do you have any idea how long the queue runs for? In my tests, it runs indefinitely. On the documentation (http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) it does not specify the lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
var requestArray = [

{
    url: 'some URL number 1'
},

{
    url: 'some URL number 2'
},

{
    url: 'some URL number 2'
}

]

function makeRequests(){

for(var i=0; i<requestArray.length; i++){
    request.get(requestArray[i].url)
    .on('response',function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(i == requestArray.length - 1)//You can check any condition here if you want to stop executing get requests{
            makeRequests();
        }
    })
  }
}
```